# Change the location from a file

Tags: java, windows, nio

Situation: I have a game, in this game you are able to record ingame with an ingame recorder (provided by the game), but you are not able to set the destination of the recorded files. All files will be saved in the game folder. So I decided to write a program which recognize in real time if a *.avi file got created, if not more in use (record is done), it will be moved to another destination. The check if the file is in use works fine, but then when im wanna move the destination of the file, I get an *java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException* That's my current code:

```
package ca.filemover;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.util.List;

public class CAWatcher {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Scan the combat arms folder...");

        while (true) {
            Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Nexon\\Combat Arms EU");

            try {
                WatchService watcher = path.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
                path.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

                WatchKey watckKey = watcher.take();

                List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watckKey.pollEvents();
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : events) {

                    String fileName = event.context().toString();
                    String filePath = path.toString();
                    String source = filePath + "\\" + fileName;

                    while (true) {
                        if (event.context().toString().contains(".avi")) {

                            if (isFileUnlocked(source)) {

                                changeFileDest(source, fileName);
                                break;

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean isFileUnlocked(String sourceFile) {
        File fileLoc = new File(sourceFile);
        return fileLoc.renameTo(fileLoc);

    }

    public static boolean changeFileDest(String source, String fileName) {

        Path moveSourcePath = Paths.get(source);
        Path moveTargetPath = Paths.get("D:\\Desktop\\CA Videos\\Reports\\" + fileName);

        try {
            Files.move(moveSourcePath, moveTargetPath);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

> java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: D:\Desktop\CA
>   Videos\Reports\CA_2015_03_30_42.avi   at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)  at
>   ca.filemover.CAWatcher.changeFileDest(CAWatcher.java:73)  at
>   ca.filemover.CAWatcher.main(CAWatcher.java:44)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand what the question is. The file already exists. What is unexpected about this?

Comment: The destination folder is empty, how can it already exists?

Comment: your error says you are trying to create a folder, which already exists, and is empty

Comment: @tnw REPLACE_EXISTING cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: idk im not used to java nio, id just do it with plain files, but that's what the error says :D, try what tnw said

Comment: @Panther `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`

Comment: @tnw this seems not working with Paths.get() ...